# Automapper : copy some properties

Tags: automapper

I have a 2 instances my class "Person"

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public List<Address> PropertyName { get; set; }      
}

var pers1 = new Person();
var pers2 = new Person();
```

Is it possible to copy a specific properties of "pers2" to "pers1" ? Is it possible to copy all properties except one from "pers2" to "pers1" ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ignore properties as you want

```
  Mapper.CreateMap<Person, Person>() 
          .ForMember(person=> person.LastName , opt => opt.Ignore())
```

Comment: Is that "merge" ? I have 2 object I'd like take some value from one and some from the other.

Comment: This is not merging. It creates new object